# Google Play 64-bit requirement App bundle failed to update

Tags: android, 32bit-64bit, android-app-bundle

We are tyring to update our App as usual but now google enforces to make the Apps compatible with 32 and 64 bit architecture. I have tried different solutions but for all cases i got this error below in the screen shot. [image]

Here is my last solution

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    ndk {
        abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    }
}

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false
        include  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    }
}
```

I also tried this `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`

Answer (score 1):

Set:

```
universalApk true
```

in order to have both architectures included in an universal APK (not App Bundle). Including `x86` and/or `x86_64` is merely useful for debug builds (emulator), but it bloats release builds with useless native assembly.

---

But for App Bundle, instead see [The base module build configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery/configure-base):

> **The splits block is ignored**:
>
> When building an app bundle, Gradle ignores properties in the `android.splits` block. If you want to control which types of configuration APKs your app bundle supports, instead use `android.bundle` to disable types of configuration APKs.

It splits by default per `abi`, but it also needs **both** `*.so`:

```
android {

    // When building Android App Bundles, the splits block is ignored.
    splits {...}

    // Instead, use the bundle block to control which types of configuration APKs
    // you want your app bundle to support.
    bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            // This property is set to true by default.
            enableSplit = true
        }
        abi {
            // This property is set to true by default.
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}
```

`ndk` build is also deprecated, use `cmake`...and make sure `arm64-v8a` `*.so` are even built (one can configure much but it does not care the least about missing libraries, until it cannot link them). Loading libraries from `armeabi` is not being accepted as "64-bit support" (already tried that).

Comment: Thanks @Martin Zeitler I tried the solution above but still unable to publish apk or bundle. Using bundle it shows me only one platform on play console armeabi-v7a however using apk analyzer it's both folders under libs arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a.

By using apk it's show 2 platforms arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a but still can't proceed to rollout the apk.

Answer (score -1):

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
    }

}

bundle {
        density {
            // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
            enableSplit true
        }
        abi {
            // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
            enableSplit true
        }
        language {
            // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
            // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
            enableSplit false
        }
    }
```